# Is this example of model object property usage unique to a logged-in session in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, security, django-models

I know django optimises with some model instance re-use. So - the question is really - is the value of 'imprints' shown below always unique to a logged-in session in django?

Lets say I have a django deployment in which, with this model.

```
Class Thing(models.Model):
    example_field = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    imprints = None  # placeholder for imprints to be added dynamically


    def add_imprints(self, cc):
        """
        Adds an imprints object associated with this instance for passed cc to this 
        instance.

        """
        self.imprints = cc.imprint_set.get(entity=self)
```

using the ORM, an instance of this Thing model in the db is pulled up in a view, say with.

```
 object = Thing.objects.get(pk=thing_id)
```

a value is then assigned to the imprints field which is intended just as an addition to the instance so that when it is passed to another function that added information is there - like this

```
object.add_imprints(cc)
```

To emphasise - the imprints value is only used to pass information with the instance of Thing during the processing of a view and through some related functions, there is no need for further persistence and it must be unique to the session.

Normally there is no problem with this kind of practice - however there may be a security issue here. I need to know if django would ever use the same instance for another logged-in user - along with the value of imprints, with a different session if they do

```
object = Thing.objects.get(pk=thing_id)
```

with the same thing_id, while the other instance is still in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django creates a new instance of the model when you retrieve a concrete object of the query.

You can be pretty confident that temporary variables will be only in that object

You can check it:

```
In [13]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

In [14]: users = User.objects.all()

In [15]: u = users.first()

In [16]: u
Out[16]: <User: super>

In [17]: u.tmp = 123

In [18]: u.tmp
Out[18]: 123

In [19]: u2 = users.first()

In [20]: u2.tmp
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-f4c979d08460> in <module>
----> 1 u2.tmp

AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'tmp'
```